# Backbone.js default path (subdomain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I am using `CORS` so all the API happens in api.mywebsite.com but the website is served via website.com.

I am wondering if there's a way I can set the setting of either  `jQuery` or `Backbone` to always make AJAX requests to my `api.mywebsite.com` ?

In otherwords, I want to do this in my backbone collections:

```
url: '/books'
```

and have it automatically infer `api.mywebsite.com/v1/books`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the collection you can specify the full URL:

```
YourApp.Collections.Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: YourApp.Models.Book,
  url: 'http://api.mywebsite.com/v1/books/'
});
```

And for individual resources you can use a function to generate the url:

```
YourApp.Models.Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    return 'http://api.mywebsite.com/v1/books/' + this.get('id')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone has the urlRoot method that sets the root of all requests.

From the Backbone site:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({urlRoot : '/books'});
var solaris = new Book({id: "1083-lem-solaris"});
alert(solaris.url());
```

alerts "/books/1083-lem-solaris"

Of-course you can change that relative path to something else: put a dot in front to send it to the site root, or your specific site root, or give it an absolute path.

[Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot)

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to use specify subdomain once and have all models use that ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course in jQuery you can build the URL to whatever you like in an AJAX request.  Including to an absolute url as long as it's not another domain:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.mywebsite.com + "anything_you_want_to_add"
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    receiveResponseMethodSomewhereElse(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And a quick Backbone example of using the url parameter of the Model or the Collection:

The  showing the scripts I used:

```
<title>Backbone Test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="underscore.js"></script>
<script src="backbone.js"></script>
```

And then I specifically pointed this backbone example at my localhost.  You'd want to point it to your domain.  I included all of the console logs and available responses for your debugging pleasure. Both options here are building urls from the book id as that's normall what your creating, Reading, Updating or Deleting from the server.  I put this script directly within the body of the page and watched the console logs.  Note: Backbone is expecting a JSON response.

```
    <script>

        var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({urlRoot: 'http://localhost/url_test'});

        var BookCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Book,
            url: 'http://localhost/url_test'
        });

        var myExcellentBook = new Book({id: "book"});

        var MyBooks = new BookCollection();

        // getting it directly from the model
        solaris.fetch({
            success: function(model, response, options) {
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                console.log(model);
                console.log(response);
                console.log(options);
            },
            error: function(model, response, options) {
                console.log("ERROR");
                console.log(model);
                console.log(response);
                console.log(options);
            },
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });

        // or fetch directly from the collection and
        // normally you'd loop through the response or
        // when creating new models, you can let backbone
        // intialize them through the response
        MyBooks.fetch({
            success: function(model, response, options) {
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                console.log(model);
                console.log(response);
                console.log(options);
            },
            error: function(model, response, options) {
                console.log("ERROR");
                console.log(model);
                console.log(response);
                console.log(options);
            },
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

And the php script at url_test is simply returning a JSON object.

```
<?php
echo '[{"id": "MyNewBook"}]';
```